# Lend me your keen eye to resolve why making this POST request is throwing an error?

Tags: javascript, next.js, prisma

I am having some issues with making a `POST` request, and having the data saved in the database.I have done this a lot of times, but somehow this time I dont know how this code is throwing a `404` error Status.
Basically, In the '/components/TeamMember.js'(`client`) - the expected bahaviour is to send the data from the form fields back to to server, and have the server save it to the database.The form input was collected, and`sendInvite` function makes the request to the`api route`.
The `sendInvite` is then pulled into `handleSubmit` function which handles whats returned back from the request.Logic is handled separately as not to confuse which function is responsible for what tasks. Also, whats more confusing is that logging the data in the`api` endpoint actually returns it as expected.I was thinking that wont be the case since theres an error on the client side.Please if you have a keen eye for bugs please let me know what more I can do to resolve this.Thanks in advance.

```
// '/api/team-members.js'
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'
import { withAccelerate } from '@prisma/extension-accelerate'

const prisma = new PrismaClient().$extends(withAccelerate())

export default async function handler(req, res) {
    try {
        // Check if the request method is POST
        if (req.method !== "POST") {
            throw new Error('Invalid HTTP method');
        }

        // Extract the user data from the request body
        const usersData = req.body;
        console.log("User Data", usersData); //Returns data as expected.


        // Check if user data is provided
        if (!usersData || !Array.isArray(usersData)) {
            return res.status(400).json({ message: "Invalid user data" });
        };

        const createdUsers = [];

        for (const userData of usersData) {
            const { email, userId } = userData;

            // Check if userId and email are provided
            if (!userId || !email) {
                return res.status(400).json({ message: "UserId and email are required" });
            };

            // Create a new record in the emailList table associated with the user
            const emailData = await prisma.emailList.create({
                data: {
                    email: email,
                    User: {
                        connect: { id: userId }
                    }
                }
            });

            

            // Find the user based on the userId
            const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
                where: {
                    id: userId
                }
            });

            if (!user) {
                return res.status(404).json({ message: "User not found" });
            }

            createdUsers.push(user);
        }

        // Respond with the created users
        res.status(200).json(createdUsers);
    } catch (error) {
        // Handle any potential errors
        res.status(500).json({ message: `Internal Server Error: ${ error.message } ` });
    }
}
```

```
// '/components/TeamMember.js'

import { Fragment, useState } from 'react';
import { Dialog, Transition } from '@headlessui/react';
import Image from 'next/image';
import Loading from './Loading';


export default function Team({ show, setShow, userId }) {
    const [state, setState] = useState(
        {
            emails: [''],
            emailMessage: 'An Invite will be sent to your team members',
            emailSent: false,
            loading: false,
        });

    const addEmailField = () => {
        setState((prevState) => ({
            ...prevState,
            emails: [...prevState.emails, ''],
        }));
    };

    const isEmailValid = (emails) => {
        const emailArray = emails.split(',').map((email) => email.trim());
        const emailRegex = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/;

        return emailArray.every((email) => emailRegex.test(email));
    };

    const handleChange = (e, index) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const { name, value } = e.target;

        // Checks if the name is 'email' and update the corresponding index in the emails array
        if (name === `email - ${ index } `) {
            setState((prevState) => {
                const updatedEmails = [...prevState.emails];
                updatedEmails[index] = value;
                return { ...prevState, emails: updatedEmails };
            });
        }
    };


    const sendInvite = async () => {
        try {
            setState((prevState) => ({
                ...prevState,
                loading: true, // Set loading to true when sending invite
            }));

            const response = await fetch('/api/team-members', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ userId: userId, emails: state.emails }),
            });
            console.log(response) //....
            return response;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error sending invite:', error);
            throw new Error('Error sending invite');
        } finally {
            setState((prevState) => ({
                ...prevState,
                loading: false, // Set loading back to false after request is complete
            }));
        }
    };

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        // checks to see if there is email entered
        if (state.emails.length === 0) {
            setState((prevState) => ({
                ...prevState,
                emailMessage: 'Please enter at least one email address.',
            }));
            return;
        }

        //validates email
        const validEmails = isEmailValid(state.emails.join(','));
        if (!validEmails) {
            setState((prevState) => ({
                ...prevState,
                emailMessage: 'Please enter valid email addresses separated by commas.',
            }));
            return;
        }

        try {
            const response = await sendInvite();
            console.log("OutRes", response)  //Throws error as shown below

            if (response.ok) {
                console.log("InRes", response) // Throws an error
                const userData = await response.json();
                setState((prevState) => ({
                    ...prevState,
                    emailSent: true,
                }));
                
            } else {
                throw new Error('Error sending invite');
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
            setState((prevState) => ({
                ...prevState,
                emailMessage: 'An error occurred while sending the invite.',
            }));
        }
    };

    console.log('WayOutRequest Payload:', { userId: userId, emails: state.emails });


    return (
        <>
        <div className="">
                                    {state.emailSent ? (
                                        <>
                                            <button
                                                type="button"
                                                onClick={() => setShow(false)}
                                                className=""
                                            >
                                                Close
                                            </button>
                                        </>
                                    ) : (
                                        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                                            <label htmlFor="email" className="">
                                                Members emails
                                            </label>
                                            <p className='text-xs'>Please enter one or more emails</p>
                                            {state.emails.map((email, index) => (
                                                <div key={index}>
                                                    <input
                                                        id={`email - ${ index } `}
                                                        name={`email - ${ index } `}
                                                        type="email"
                                                        onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, index)}
                                                        autoComplete="email"
                                                        value={email}
                                                        required
                                                        className=""
                                                        placeholder="email@example.com"
                                                    />
                                                    {index === state.emails.length - 1 && (
                                                        <button
                                                            type="button"
                                                            onClick={addEmailField}
                                                            className=""
                                                        >
                                                            Add Another Email
                                                        </button>
                                                    )}
                                                </div>
                                            ))}
                                            <button
                                                type="submit"
                                                className=""
                                            >
                                                Submit
                                            </button>
                                        </form>
                                    )}
                                </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

```
// Error
 POST http://localhost:3000/api/team-members 400 (Bad Request)

 client.js:1  Error fetching data: Error: Error sending invite
    at handleSubmit (VM60619 TeamMembers.js:117:23)

 Response {type: 'basic', url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/team-members', redirected: false, status: 400, ok: false, …}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: false
redirected: false
status: 400
statusText: "Bad Request"
type : "basic"
url: "http://localhost:3000/api/team-members"
```